# How can I pivot a column in Excel have have the values in the same line instead of adding one line per value?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have this table:

| Origin | Destination | Service | Supplier | Weight | Currency | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JFK | SYD | Lower | DHL | 0-45 | USD | 2.63 |
| JFK | SYD | Lower | DHL | 45-100 | USD | 2.63 |
| JFK | SYD | Lower | DHL | 100-200 | USD | 2.63 |
| EWR | FRA | Lower | DHL | 0-45 | USD | 2.50 |
| EWR | FRA | Lower | DHL | 45-100 | USD | 2.70 |
| EWR | FRA | Lower | DHL | 100-200 | USD | 2.80 |

And I want it like this:

| Origin | Destination | Service | Supplier | Currency | 0-45 | 45-100 | 100-200 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JFK | SYD | Lower | DHL | USD | 2.63 | 2.63 | 2.63 |
| EWR | FRA | Lower | DHL | USD | 2.50 | 2.70 | 2.80 |

When I use the "pivot column" option in Power Query, I get this:

| Origin | Destination | Service | Supplier | Currency | 0-45 | 45-100 | 100-200 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JFK | SYD | Lower | DHL | USD | 2.63 |  |  |
| JFK | SYD | Lower | DHL | USD |  | 2.63 |  |
| JFK | SYD | Lower | DHL | USD |  |  | 2.63 |
| EWR | FRA | Lower | DHL | USD | 2.50 |  |  |
| EWR | FRA | Lower | DHL | USD |  | 2.70 |  |
| EWR | FRA | Lower | DHL | USD |  |  | 2.80 |

How can I have the values in the same row instead of multiple?

Answer (score 0):

In powerquery

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Source, List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Weight]), "Weight", "Price", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

click select weight column, transform .. pivot column ... values column:price